# deserialize json without property name .Net

Tags: .net, json, deserialization

I'm using JSON.NET to deserialize response from HTTP, but I'm stuck with an issue. That's because the response sending results wthout property names
i have something like this

{"people":{"jack":{"condition":"good","version":"1.0.5"},"jim":{"condition":"bad","version":"1.0.5"}},"hede":14,"hodo":"apple"}

how can I put this in a class.

not: json result can have more than jack and jim when i paste as a class it creates jim and jack classes. bob and mike will come soon.

sorry bro. i was just writing my effort but my daughter woke up. went to send her to bed back. what I mean is, after searching "good" in dictionaries i want to go back and find "jack".

```
var values = from value in dictioanries.values 
where value.condition ="good" 
select new { value.condition, value.version }
```

ok here I searched the dictionaries, there are 2 of them(jack and jim) i want to know under which dictionary i found "good"

Comment: Copy the json, Open your VS, then `Edit / Paste Special / Paste JSON as Classes` ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a class as much as you have a dictionary of string and objects. If you do the following, you should be able to deserialize properly:

```
public class PeopleResponse
{
  public Dictionary<string, Info> people { get; set; }
  public string hede { get; set; }
  public string hodo { get; set; }
}

public class Info
{
  public string condition { get; set; }
  public string version { get; set; }
}
```

From there, you should be able to do:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PeopleResponse>("{myJSONGoesHere}");
```

Edit: Based on your updated question, if you would like to get the names of all whose condition is "good," you can do the following (assuming your deserialized object is called `results`:

```
var goodStuff = from p in results.people 
                where p.Value.condition.ToLower() == "good" 
                select p.Key;
```

You could, of course, just get `p` instead of `p.Key`, which would return the entire key/value pair.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your comment? Is the JSON response always different? Are you having issues making that work? ...

Comment: @ManuelCalavera Given your json, It **does work** like that... You may try to show your effort, instead of just responding *it does not work like that*

Comment: sorry bro. i was just writing my effort but my daughter woke up. went to send her to bed back. what I mean is, after searching "good" in dictionaries i want to go back and find "jack".                                           var values = from value in dictioanries.values
                             where value.condition ="good"  
                             select  new { value.condition, value.version } ;      ok here I searched the dctionaries there are 2 (jack and jim) i want to know under which dictionary i found "good"

Comment: @ManuelCalavera : I've updated my answer to show how a LINQ query for that condition would work.